# Is there a <# #> tag? and If not what use could it have in this code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently inspected the source of some website and saw the following code

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-playlist-settings">
    <h2>Playlist Settings</h2>

    <# var emptyModel = _.isEmpty( data.model ),
        isVideo = 'video' === data.controller.get('library').props.get('type'); #>

    <label class="setting">
        <input type="checkbox" data-setting="tracklist" <# if ( emptyModel ) { #>
            checked="checked"
        <# } #> />
        <# if ( isVideo ) { #>
        <span>Show Video List</span>
        <# } else { #>
        <span>Show Tracklist</span>
        <# } #>
    </label>

    <# if ( ! isVideo ) { #>
    <label class="setting">
        <input type="checkbox" data-setting="artists" <# if ( emptyModel ) { #>
            checked="checked"
        <# } #> />
        <span>Show Artist Name in Tracklist</span>
    </label>
    <# } #>

    <label class="setting">
        <input type="checkbox" data-setting="images" <# if ( emptyModel ) { #>
            checked="checked"
        <# } #> />
        <span>Show Images</span>
    </label>
</script>
```

I recognized the code uses the "echoing" style of php ( putting code html inside a conditional IF statement), although the code is inside `<# #>`.
I've never seen that approach before. What use could it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a wordpress template, Arbitrary logic goes in carrot hash template tags <# //logic #>.

More information can be found here https://lkwdwrd.com/wp-template-js-templates-wp/

This may not only apply to wordpress.

```
 <# if ( data.trueValue ) { #>
     <p> I am only output if <code>data.trueValue</code> is true.
 <# } #>
```

But may apply to other templating languages aswell, other variations may be:

`<% ... %>`, `{{...}}` and so on, depending on the templating engine.

Comment: @7asobate- you should accept the answer if it solves your problem