# Adding a conditional to mustache/php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mustache, mustache.php

Consider:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single variation display
 *
 * This is a javascript-based template for single variations (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template).
 * The values will be dynamically replaced after selecting attributes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>

    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>

    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
        GTIN: <span class="sku">{{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}}</span>
    </div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
        MPN: <span class="sku">{{{ data.variation.wccaf_mpn }}}</span>
    </div>

</script>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-unavailable-variation-template">
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
</script>
```

How do I implement a conditional, such that IF `{{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}}` returns blank/empty value, THEN echo "GTIN unavailable"?

What I have tried:

I have read this on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustache_(template_system)#Examples):

> Template with section tag:
>
> {{#x}} Some text {{/x}} Here, when x is a Boolean value then the
>   section tag acts like an if conditional

So I tried

```
 <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
        GTIN: <span class="sku">{{#repo}}{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}{{/repo}}{{^repo}}N/A{{/repo}}</span>
    </div>
```

which doesn't work.

But I'm completely new to mustache and I need some guidance.

Comment: The `mustache` is good. But you can check this also www.github.com/Redcof/ints-jst

Answer (score 3):

That is not a Mustache template, as comment notes it's WordPress custom `wp.template` solution.

It doesn't have any logic tags, but has evaluate tags `<# #>`.

From quick google here is an example how would you write a check using them:

```js
  <# if ( data.trueValue ) { #>
    <p> I am only output if <code>data.trueValue</code> is true.
  <# } #>
```

Via https://lkwdwrd.com/wp-template-js-templates-wp

Comment: Would you mind re-writing that solution so that if `{{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}}` returns blank/empty value, then echo "GTIN unavailable"?  I wouldn't know how to adapt it myself, thanks.

Comment: Would be something like `<# if ( ! data.variation.wccaf_gtin ) { #>`

Comment: `<# if(isEmpty(data.variation.wccaf_gtin)) { #>
    <p> I am only output if <code>data.variation.wccaf_gtin</code> is true.
  <# } #>`  Would this be correct usage?  (I don't know either mustache or JS.)

Comment: So to show a "placeholder" text if a value is empty, I believe it should look like this:


`<# if ( data.variation.wccaf_gtin ) { #>
    <p>{{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}}</p>
<# } else { #>
    <p>GTIN unavailable</p>
<# } #>`

That being said, I've never worked with WP templates, or not in the last few years so I'm just thinking that should do it. You could wrap the condition in `isEmpty` if the check would fail otherwise

Comment: @kachnitel I tried your code plus also with the `isEmpty`:  `<# if isEmpty( data.variation.wccaf_gtin ) { #> <p>{{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}}</p> <# } else { #> <p>GTIN unavailable</p> <# } #>`  No luck, friend, try again?

Comment: Odd, I've done some quick search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853993/is-there-a-tag-and-if-not-what-use-could-it-have-in-this-code) which uses the same idea in an existing code `<# if ( isVideo ) { #>
        <span>Show Video List</span>
        <# } else { #>
        <span>Show Tracklist</span>
        <# } #>`
Are you getting any output at all with that one above?

Comment: @kachnitel  There's a caveat on that answer which says `This may not only apply to wordpress.`  Do you suppose that might have something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mustache Documentation](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

```
// if exist
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>        
{{/repo}}

// if not exist
{{^repo}}
  No repos :(
{{/repo}}
```

You may try this

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
        GTIN: <span class="sku">{{#data.variation.wccaf_gtin}}{{ data.variation.wccaf_gtin }}{{/data.variation.wccaf_gtin}}{{^data.variation.wccaf_gtin}}N/A{{/data.variation.wccaf_gtin}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the same using [ints-jst](https://github.com/Redcof/ints-jst)

**Code:**

```
<div id="try-jst">
            <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
                <js-t> print(data.variation.variation_description);</js-t>
            </div>

            <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
                <js-t> print(data.variation.price_html);</js-t>
            </div>

            <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">
                <js-t> print(data.variation.availability_html);</js-t>
            </div>

            <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
                GTIN:
                <span class="sku">
            <js-t>
                if(!!data.variation.wccaf_gtin) {
                   print(data.variation.wccaf_gtin);
                } else {
                   print("unavailable");
                }
            </js-t>
        </span>
            </div>
            <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
                MPN:
                <span class="sku">
            <js-t>
                if(!!data.variation.wccaf_mpn) {
                   print(data.variation.wccaf_mpn);
                } else {
                   print("unavailable");
                }
            </js-t>
        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    /* var data = {
        variation: {
            variation_description: 'variation_description',
            price_html: 'price_html',
            availability_html: 'availability_html',
            wccaf_gtin: '',
            wccaf_mpn: '123',
        }
    }; */
    // jQuery version
    compile($('#try-jst')[0]);
    run();

    // Plain Javascript
    /**
     * compile(document.getElementById('try-jst'));
     * run();
     */
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
<div id="try-jst">
                <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">variation_description</div>
                <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">price_html</div>
                <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">availability_html</div>
                <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field"> GTIN: <span class="sku">unavailable</span></div>
                <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field"> MPN: <span class="sku">123</span></div>
            </div>
```

So you can give it a try.